# Where can I find information on the percentage of volume is contributed by shorts?

Tags: united-states, canada, shorting-securities

Is it possible to get the information as to what percentage of the average daily volume of a stock or ETF is due to short sellers? This can mean either people selling short or buying back to cover their short.

I am still not sure how this information will be helpful (if at all) but I think it will help to explain some rapid volume towards the end of the day when shorts are covering their positions.

Comment: What country? What markets? You should always tag accordingly (for the country) and mention in your question when a tag isn't available. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it's not possible for the public to know what shares are being exchanged as shorts because broker-dealers (not the exchanges) handle the shorting arrangements.  I don't think exchanges can even tell the difference between a person selling a share that belongs to her vs. a share that she's just borrowing.  (There are SEC regulations requiring some traders to declare that trades are shorts, but (a) I don't think this applies to all traders, (b) it only applies to the sells, and (c) this information isn't public.)

That being said, you *can* view the [short interest](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shortinterest.asp) in a symbol using any of a number of tools, such as Nasdaq's [here](http://www.nasdaq.com/quotes/short-interest.aspx).  This is often cited as an indicator similar to what you proposed, though I don't know how helpful it would be from an *intra*-day perspective.

Comment: yeah, you can do a lot of deduction, there is also a list of regulation-sho securities

Answer (score 1):

You can do a lot of deduction

FINRA keeps a "REG-SHO" list created daily that tells what the daily short volume is.

March 26th 2014's list: http://regsho.finra.org/FNSQshvol20140326.txt

If you are talking about the United States, this answer may be better ;)

Comment: Thanks, what is short exempt volume in that link?